# conversion de String a int Array bidimensional

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

Necesito convertir, en un `Array bidimensional`, de `String` a `int`, pero son muchos valores y me sale mucho código, cómo puedo optimizarlo?

para pasar a `int` el contenido de un `array bidimensional` `tipo String`

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(bi [0][1]="8");
a=8;
```

Pero he de hacer eso por cada dato? sería interminable en un `array` de muchos datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un `for` para recorrer tu array bidimensional de tipo `String` y luego almacenar los valores en el tipo `int`. Un ejemplo seria este

```
    String  [][] arrayString = new String[3][3];
    int  [][] arrayNumero = new int[3][3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
        {
            arrayString[i][x]="1";

            arrayNumero[i][x]=Integer.parseInt(arrayString[i][x]);
            System.out.print(arrayNumero[i][x]);
        }

    }
```

En este caso llené mi array `String` con puros números `1` y luego llené mi array `int` parseando los valores que reciba el array tipo `String`.

Comment: Pero los números almacenados en mi array String, NO son consecutivos y hay cuatro que son los nombres de las asignaturas

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código te convierte tus números válidos a int y los agrega a una lista.

```
List<Integer> listaInt = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < arrayString[0].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < arrayString[1].length; j++){
        if(isNumber(arrayString[i][j])){
            listaInt.add(Integer.valueOf(arrayString[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public boolean isNumber(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.valueOf(str);            
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException w) {            
        return false;
    }
}
```